# Folder Watcher bash script: also check for subfolders

Tags: bash, file, directory

**EDIT:**

*I've improved this "FolderWatcher script" of user konsolebox (from the answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18597233/2095175 )
I have added these lines to automatically move every kind of file in a right folder on my system (eg pdf in /Docs folder, Images in /Picture and video files in /Videos)*

```
extension=${ADDED##*.}
if [ "$extension" = "xz" ] || [ "$extension" = "zip" ] || [ "$extension" = "gz" ] || [ "$extension" = "bz2" ] || [ "$extension" = "7z" ]; then
open $ADDED
fi
if [ "$extension" = "pdf" ] || [ "$extension" = "txt" ] || [ "$extension" = "odt" ] || [ "$extension" = "doc" ] ; then
mv "$ADDED" /boot/home/Docs
alert --idea " $ADDED moved to /boot/home/Docs"
open /boot/home/Docs
fi
if [ "$extension" = "jpg" ] || [ "$extension" = "png" ] || [ "$extension" = "gif" ]; then
mv "$ADDED" /boot/home/Media/Images
alert --idea " $ADDED moved to /boot/home/Media/Images"
open /boot/home/Media/Images
fi
if [ "$extension" = "flv" ] || [ "$extension" = "avi" ] || [ "$extension" = "mp4" ] || [ "$extension" = "mpg" ]; then
mv "$ADDED" /boot/home/Media/Video
alert --idea " $ADDED moved to /boot/home/Media/Video"
open /boot/home/Media/Video
fi
```

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

i have the following script which continuously check for the content of a folder, and alert me whenever a new file is inserted and/or when is deleted. Works perfectly as expected. But doesn't check subfolders in the main folder ( folder=$(cat /boot/home/FolderWatcher_pref.txt) )
Eg if I insert/remove file from the main folder, i will be alerted, but if i insert/remove files in a subfolder of "$folder", the script is not able to alert me. What can i change or add in this script to achieve this need?

I am on Haiku OS, so some command like "alert" are Haiku-specific.

```
    #!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                                         

    cat /dev/null > $difffile1
    cat /dev/null > $difffile2

    #The path where to look is set in a text file, which i can change with a file panel to select any folder
    folder=$(cat /boot/home/FolderWatcher_pref.txt) 
    tstamp=$(stat --print "%Y" "$folder")

    while true; do
    prev=$(ls "$folder" | tr '\n' '\n'  > /tmp/prev.txt)
    sleep 5

    if [[ "$folder" == "$folder" && $tstamp -lt $(stat --print "%Y" "$folder") ]]; then
    after=$(ls "$folder" | tr '\n' '\n'  > /tmp/after.txt)


    difference1=$(comm -2 -3 "/tmp/after.txt" "/tmp/prev.txt">/tmp/Diff.txt)
    added=$(cat /boot/common/cache/tmp/Diff.txt)


    difference2=$(comm -2 -3 "/tmp/prev.txt" "/tmp/after.txt">/tmp/Diff2.txt)
    lost=$(cat /boot/common/cache/tmp/Diff2.txt)


    difffile1=/tmp/Diff.txt
    difffile2=/tmp/Diff2.txt
    FILESIZE2=$(stat -c%s "$difffile2")
    if [ "$FILESIZE2" == 0 ]
    then 
    lost=nothing
    fi
    FILESIZE1=$(stat -c%s "$difffile1")
    if [ "$FILESIZE1" == 0 ]
    then 
    added=nothing

    fi

    lost2=$(cat /boot/common/cache/tmp/Diff2.txt)
    alert --idea "$folder:

    $added
    *INSERTED*.

    $lost
    *REMOVED*."; 

    echo "$lost2" >>$folder/Removed.txt

    tstamp=$(stat --print "%Y" "$folder")

    cat /dev/null > $difffile1
    cat /dev/null > $difffile2
        else                                                                                                                                                                                            
            sleep 3;                                                                                                                                                                                    
        fi                                                                                                                                                                                              
    done
```

Comment: This line is a little weird: `prev=$(ls "$folder" | tr '\n' '\n'  > /tmp/prev.txt)`. Interesting script by the way..

Comment: This line print the content of the folder to a temp text file.
Then is compared with after=$(ls "$folder" | tr '\n' '\n'  > /tmp/after.txt). to the diff.txt to obtain the name of the file which is added or removed (with diff2.txt)

Comment: @konsolebox look at my question: i have made some improvements to your script: let me know what you think :-)

Comment: Since extglob is already enabled, your comparisons like `[ "$extension" = "xz" ] || [ "$extension" = "zip" ] || [ "$extension" = "gz" ] || [ "$extension" = "bz2" ] || [ "$extension" = "7z" ]; then` could just be simplified as `[[ $extension == @(xz|zip|gz|bz2|7z) ]]`. You could also ignore the case by doing `shopt -s nocaseglob`. And better quote your variable: `open "$ADDED"`. I think everything's good with that already.

Comment: @konsolebox "shopt -s nocaseglob" for what is needed?

Comment: When you compare with glob expressions or do pathname expansions, the case would not matter when making a match. As an example instead of doing `[[ $extension == @(gz|GZ) ]]`, you could just do `[[ $extension == @(gz) ]]` when `shopt -s nocaseglob` is enabled. `[[ $extension == @(xz|zip|gz|bz2|7z) ]]` as well would match extensions in uppercase versions if that's the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I end up making my own modification but this one works and no longer uses temporary files. It uses `find` and `process substitution`.

```
#!/bin/bash

[ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ] && [[ BASH_VERSINFO -ge 3 ]] || {
    echo "You need bash version 3.0 or newer to run this script." >&2
    exit 1
}

shopt -s extglob

FOLDER=$(</boot/home/FolderWatcher_pref.txt)
REMOVED_LOG="$FOLDER/Removed.txt"  ## It's better to place this somewhere not in "$FOLDER" to not confuse timestamps everytime it is updated.

if [[ ! -d $FOLDER ]]; then
    echo "Directory does not exist: $FOLDER" >&2
elif read TIMESTAMP < <(exec find "$FOLDER" -type d -printf "%T@\n" | cut -f 1 -d . | sort -nr); [[ $TIMESTAMP != +([[:digit:]]) ]]; then
    echo "Unable to get timestamp of directory: $FOLDER" >&2
else
    STATE=$(exec find "$FOLDER" -mindepth 1 | sort)

    for (( ;; )); do
        sleep 5

        if [[ -d $FOLDER ]] && read NEWTIMESTAMP < <(exec find "$FOLDER" -type d -printf "%T@\n" | cut -f 1 -d . | sort -nr) && [[ NEWTIMESTAMP -gt TIMESTAMP ]]; then
            NEWSTATE=$(exec find "$FOLDER" -mindepth 1 | sort)

            ADDED=$(comm -2 -3 <(echo "$NEWSTATE") <(echo "$STATE"))
            [[ -z $ADDED ]] && ADDED='nothing'

            LOST=$(comm -2 -3 <(echo "$STATE") <(echo "$NEWSTATE"))
            LOST_ORIG=$LOST
            [[ -z $LOST ]] && LOST='nothing'

            alert --idea "$FOLDER:

$ADDED
*INSERTED*.

$LOST
*REMOVED*."

            [[ -n $LOST_ORIG ]] && echo "$LOST_ORIG" >> "$REMOVED_LOG"

            read TIMESTAMP < <(exec find "$FOLDER" -type d -printf "%T@\n" | cut -f 1 -d . | sort -nr) && [[ TIMESTAMP -ge NEWTIMESTAMP ]] || TIMESTAMP=$NEWTIMESTAMP
            STATE=$NEWSTATE
        fi
    done
fi
```

Comment: It works. Except for the fact that if i remove files from any subfolder, i'm not alerted. I am only alerted of removed f iles, if i remove file from the main folder. In anyway thank you, it was what i was looking for!

Comment: @Giova84 I expect it to show the files removed from the subfolders as well since `find` is recursive. Does it not do that?

Comment: I have also noticed that: if i remove or add files inside subfolders, from another folder (which ain't $folder), i am not alerted. I am alerted for subfolders only if i move file from $folder, inside subfolders.

Comment: @Giova84 I made an update. I hope it works now :) Please tell me if again you notice something wrong.

Comment: Now it works like a charm!!! Im sad about the fact that i cannot vote your answers, since i need 15 reputation! You was very gentle :-)

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you use [inotifywait](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait) or [inotifywatch](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywatch) ? You can use `-r` flag to make it recursive. 
Take a look at [inotify-tools](https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki).
You may be interested in [incron](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=about&lang=en) as well.

Comment: On Haiku we don't have inotify-tools. nor incron

Comment: @Giova84 oh, I see. Sorry. I wont remove this answer just in case somebody else finds this question.

Comment: Don't you worry, in fact could be useful for someone else :-)

Answer (score 0):

You want to augment this line:

```
prev=$(ls "$folder" | tr '\n' '\n'  > /tmp/prev.txt)
```

to something like:

```
prev=$(ls "$folder"/* | tr '\n' '\n'  > /tmp/prev.txt)
```

Comment: Actually he doesn't even need to use the variable `prev` since the script compares the files instead.

Comment: Doesn't work.. And in anyway i have also to add "| sort |". Another suggestion?

Comment: How about using `find` then?  Can always pipe it's output of filenames (using `-print`) into `xargs`.

Comment: Can you give a practical example, Paul? Thank you.